# Using Freeform - have form errors display in modal window (Fancybox) without closing

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm working on a form (using Freeform) that lives in a modal box (become a partner on this page: http://framework.tunnel7.com/partners

What I'm trying to accomplish is having the error messages displayed inline (I have those parameters in place) when a user hits submit in the same modal window.

What is happening now is on submit the modal closes and if you click on the become a member button again it displays with the errors inline (so it's working) ... but I can't see a way to keep the modal open if there is an error.

Is there a way to accomplish this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

I use the jQuery Validation Plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

with Freeform and it works really well. With it, the form is not sent (no page reload) until all errors are gone, and there is a lot of flexibility in customising the validations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.post() to submit the form, then give the user feedback based on the response you receive. If you get an error, you tell the user about it, either within the modal or on a dedicated error page. If the form submitted successfully you either update the modal right there on the page or redirect the user to some sort of success/thank you page.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts on this.  have put this on the back burner but will be returning to it soon.